# own completion handler in firebase function (custom class method)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, completionhandler

I would like to update some init values of a method asynchronously, but I don't find a way to respect the firebase completion, so I m trying to do my own one, but with no luck, any idea ? (in the following code, I am trying to update the values of comlike)

```
class POSTDATA {

var comcount : String
var comlike : Int
var post : getitems

init(comcount:String, comlike:Int, post:getitems) {

    self.post = post
    self.comlike = comlike
    self.comcount = comcount
    findComCount(){success in}
}

func findComCount(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) {

    let refComCount = Firebase (url: ("https://XXXXXX/COMCOUNTS/" + self.post.postid + "/comcount"))
    refComCount.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
        if snap.value is NSNull {
             self.comcount = "0"

        } else {
            if snap.value == nil {
                 self.comcount = "0"
            } else {
                 self.comcount = String( snap.value!)
            }
            }

        completionHandler(true)
    })

}
```

}

Comment: What's preventing the values from being updated inside the block when Firebase returns them?

Comment: in fact I want to use this method later on in a VC, so I would do something like let data:POSTDATA("0", 0, post) and right after get the POSTDATA value, but since the completion is not done, the parameters return nil

Comment: This setup is really not leveraging Firebases asynchronous nature and may actually making the code more complicated than it needs to be. You should let firebase tell your app when there's new data and then update accordingly. That will eliminate the need to use the method in multiple places as the data updates are handled in one block and the data will always be valid since firebase is handling updating you app.

Comment: in a complex app, firebase completion handlers are really annoying. It s good, robust and fast, but the way it deals with its own async system forces you to multiply your code multiple times, think about a search fonction and a fetching option, the search will give you a list of ids to observe, while a fetch would be a query. both of them calling exactly the same sub fetching code. Initating sub observers through a method simplifies the global architecture and keeps tracks of obervers. The answer from EzieHammer is really nice since it implicates a straighforward waiting in line solution

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question but clarify, there are no search or fetch functions in Firebase. When you want firebase to tell you about an event or retrieve the content of a specific node(s), you add an Observer. When you want to look for specific data, Query. Once you attach an observer, it sticks - you don't need to duplicate your code. You would generally not need to search to get a list of id's to observe. Sometimes simpler is better but again, I am probably misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I will soon make a small tutorial on Firebase nested data deep observers tricky issues when doing complex architecture queries VS observers, what i meant is, sometimes you have to query and then sub observe something in your data base (this is a fetch) and sometimes you need to batch observe and then sub observe, well nevertheless, thank you for taking time to answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing async operation in the init call is quite strange, instead you could use something like dynamic variables and KVO observing:

```
class POSTDATA:NSObject { //Inherit your class from NSObject to allow KVO observing

        var comcount : String
        var comlike : Int
        var post : getitems

    dynamic var completed:Bool = false //Here you declare your dynamic var


        init(comcount:String, comlike:Int, post:getitems) {

            self.post = post
            self.comlike = comlike
            self.comcount = comcount
            findComCount();
        }

        func findComCount() {

            let refComCount = Firebase (url: ("https://XXXXXX/COMCOUNTS/" + self.post.postid + "/comcount"))
            refComCount.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in
                if snap.value is NSNull {
                     self.comcount = "0"

                } else {
                    if snap.value == nil {
                         self.comcount = "0"
                    } else {
                         self.comcount = String( snap.value!)
                    }
                    }

                self.completed = true //Assign to it value 'true' when update i completed
            })

        }
        }
```

Then in your viewController you do something like this:

```
var postDataObject:POSTDATA = POSTDATA("String",0,getitemObj);

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        postDataObject.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "completed", options: NSKeyValueObservingOption, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
     if (keyPath != nil){
        if(keyPath!=="completed"){
              //HERE YOU KNOW YOUR OBJECT HAS BEEN UPDATED
         }
     }
    }

    deinit {
        postDataObject.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "completed", context: nil)
    }
```

Comment: beautifull, didnt think about a dynamic var